# How can I compare different date values

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have date column on my database like this:

```
201411241440
```

year month day hour minute

I need to compare it with now and if it's older than 1 day, do something, else do something.

I think, I can do like this on regular date format

```
DateTime isold = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
```

And compare.

How can I do this with my date format? And how can I compare date values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this is a `DateTime` value, you can use [`.AddDays()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and compare with [`<`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5wecxwa.aspx) and [`>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxk8751b.aspx) operators.

```
if(yourDateTime < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))
{ 
   // do something.
}
```

If this is a `string` value, you can use [custom date and time formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) and compare with `<` and `>` operators.

```
string s = "201411241440";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyyMMddHHmm",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    if(dt < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))
    { 
        // do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: @volkanasr Just change `DateTime.UtcNow` to `DateTime.Now`.